# Add a cart fee from an url variable in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

With Woocommerce, [this website](https://milanshopping.co.uk) has two types of buttons for products:

1. Add to shopping bag and
2. Contact us to order.

When clicked on "Contact us to order" button, visitors get redirected to a contact form in "Contact us to order" page. This contact form is built with Contact form 7 plugin.

For some of the products, the contact form has an exclusive checkbox field where they get to choose the lining. Based on which lining they chose, I am redirecting the visitors to the checkout page with some value passed through the URL.

For example: `https://milanshopping.co.uk/checkout/?val=15`

And in the `functions.php` file, I am using the following code:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','milanshopping_add_lining_fees' ); 
 function milanshopping_add_lining_fees() { 
     if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
         return;

    if(isset($_GET['val'])){

        if($_GET['val'] == 15){
            $leather_fee = 15;
        }else{
            $leather_fee = 20;  
        } 

    }

    if($leather_fee != 0 ){
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Leather fee', $leather_fee);        
    }    

}
```

But this fails to add the fee even though the `$_GET` value is present. I have checked by calling the echo `$_GET['val']` and the value is printed.

But if I add the following code outside the if statement,

```
WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Leather fee', $leather_fee);
```

it works though fee added is 0 and not the fees I am trying to generate from the `$_GET` value. Any idea?

Redirection from contact us to order page to checkout page is done using the Contact form 7 dom event "wpcf7submit" and products are added to cart using a separate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: You need to grab the queried url variable value in sessions first, this way:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'grab_fee_query_var' );
function grab_fee_query_var() {
    session_start();

    // Not on checkout page
    if( ! is_admin() && isset($_GET['val']) ) {
        $_SESSION['leather_fee'] = $_GET['val'];
        WC()->session->__unset('leather_fee');
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','add_custom_cart_fee' );
function add_custom_cart_fee() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if(isset($_SESSION['leather_fee']) && ! WC()->session->__isset('leather_fee') ){
        $value = $_SESSION['leather_fee'] == 15 ? 15 : 20;
        WC()->session->set('leather_fee', $value );
    }

    if( WC()->session->__isset('leather_fee') ) {
       $leather_fee = WC()->session->get('leather_fee');
       WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Leather fee', $leather_fee);
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I have added your code and it works but then there's this problem. The Leather fee gets added when the checkout page first loads but immediately gets removed. You can check that live in https://milanshopping.co.uk/shop/ select second or third product and in the contact form, chose a lining.

Comment: Now the fee does get added but after I choose a lining for the first time, from then on, all the products get the leather fee added to them even though contact form doesn't even have the option to chose the lining for those products. Thank you so much for the help so far. I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: @ZihadUlIslam I have tested this code and it works just fine regarding the material you provided in your question. My answer code just illustrate the way to grab a value from a query string to be used as a cart fee. Everyone need to adapt the code to its own context.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I was able to get around of the problem I mentioned in the above comment. By unsetting the session variables when not in the checkout page. Had to use the template_redirect hook.